# Dynamic table in SQL query using union

Tags: oracle

I have below query and it is not working

```
with mag_re as(
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table1 
    where 'condition'

    union all

    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table2
    where 'condition'
)
select t.a as "A", t.b as "B", M.b as "BB"
from table3 t, mag_re M
where t.a = M.A

union all

select t.a as "A", t.b as "B", M.b as "BB"
from table4 t, mag_re M
where t.a = M.A
```

It is not working, I have the query same as above.
I just want to run some query and store into that dynamic table.
By using that dynamic table I want to get some data.

Original data:

```
with market_reg as (
select  acc.account_name,
        rc1.code_label 
        from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,reference_Code rc1
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level = 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and rc1.reference_code = cnh.general_1
and rc1.reference_type_id = 1012882
union 
select   acc.account_name,
        rc1.code_label 
from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,reference_Code rc1,
account  acc1,customer_node_history cnh1
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and acc.account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level != 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and cnh.root_customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc1.account_type_id = 10000
and sysdate between cnh1.effective_start_date and cnh1.effective_end_date
and cnh1.customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and rc1.reference_code = cnh.general_1
and rc1.reference_type_id = 1012882)
select  sc.schedule_name "SCHEDULE_NAME",
        acc.account_name "ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh.node_name "NODE_NAME",
        cnt.customer_node_type_name "Market Segment",cnh.Hierarchy_level, acc.account_name "ROOT_ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh.node_name "ROOT_NODE_NAME",
        mr.code_label "Market Region"
        from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,market_reg mr
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level = 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and acc.account_name = mr.ACCOUNT_NAME
union 
with market_reg as (
select  acc.account_name,
        rc1.code_label 
        from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,reference_Code rc1
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level = 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and rc1.reference_code = cnh.general_1
and rc1.reference_type_id = 1012882
union 
select   acc.account_name,
        rc1.code_label 
from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,reference_Code rc1,
account  acc1,customer_node_history cnh1
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and acc.account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level != 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and cnh.root_customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc1.account_type_id = 10000
and sysdate between cnh1.effective_start_date and cnh1.effective_end_date
and cnh1.customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and rc1.reference_code = cnh.general_1
and rc1.reference_type_id = 1012882)
select  sc.schedule_name "SCHEDULE_NAME",
        acc.account_name "ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh.node_name "NODE_NAME",
        cnt.customer_node_type_name "Market Segment",cnh.Hierarchy_level, acc1.account_name "ROOT_ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh1.node_name "ROOT_NODE_NAME",
        mr.code_label "Market Region"
from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,
account  acc1,customer_node_history cnh1,,market_reg mr
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and acc.account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level != 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and cnh.root_customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc1.account_type_id = 10000
and sysdate between cnh1.effective_start_date and cnh1.effective_end_date
and cnh1.customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc.account_name = mr.ACCOUNT_NAME
```

I get error as **"unsupported use of WITH clause"**

Comment: "It is not working" is not helpful. What happens? Do you get an error? (Your column aliases are wrong - single quotes are for literals, not identifiers, so should be `as "A"` etc. Also look into using modern join syntax).

Comment: Sorry for that. I am using " ". I get error as **"unsupported use of WITH clause"**

Comment: Then edit your question to show what you are actually running. You may be hiding the real problem by changing names. Is this part of a larger statement - maybe creating a view? (Not sure what you mean by a dynamic table here, perhaps explain what you are trying to schieve).

Comment: Added original query in question.

Comment: That doesn't match what you first showed. You're repeating the `with` clause.

Comment: Thanks man. I thought I should use with clause twice. Now it works.Is there any other optimized solution for above scenario Alex.

Comment: You should use the ANSI join syntax instead of the old Oracle join syntax, it is less error-prone. For example, you put two comma in your list of tables: `customer_node_history cnh1,,market_reg mr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real code you posted isn't doing what your original simplified code showed. You're actually doing something more like:

```
with mag_re as(
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table1 
    where 'condition' = 'x'
    union all
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table2
    where 'condition' = 'x'
)
select t.a as "A", t.b as "B", M.b as "BB"
from table3 t, mag_re M
where t.a = M.A
union all
with mag_re as(
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table1 
    where 'condition' = 'x'
    union all
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table2
    where 'condition' = 'x'
)
select t.a as "A", t.b as "B", M.b as "BB"
from table4 t, mag_re M
where t.a = M.A;

SQL Error: ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
*Cause:    Inproper use of WITH clause because one of the following two reasons
           1. nesting of WITH clause within WITH clause not supported yet
           2. For a set query, WITH clause can't be specified for a branch.
           3. WITH clause cannot be specified within parenthesis.
*Action:   correct query and retry
```

You have repeated the `with` clause in each half of your main union, which is incorrect and is causing the error. Part of the point of subquery factoring is to stop you having to repeat code. So (ironically) your initial simplified code is actually fine, as the `with` was *not* repeated:

```
with mag_re as(
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table1 
    where 'condition' = 'x'
    union all
    select a as "A", b as "B"
    from table2
    where 'condition' = 'x'
)
select t.a as "A", t.b as "B", M.b as "BB"
from table3 t, mag_re M
where t.a = M.A
union all
select t.a as "A", t.b as "B", M.b as "BB"
from table4 t, mag_re M
where t.a = M.A;
```

For your real code just remove the second `with` clause:

```
with market_reg as (
select  acc.account_name,
        rc1.code_label 
        from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,reference_Code rc1
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level = 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and rc1.reference_code = cnh.general_1
and rc1.reference_type_id = 1012882
union 
select   acc.account_name,
        rc1.code_label 
from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,reference_Code rc1,
account  acc1,customer_node_history cnh1
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and acc.account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level != 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and cnh.root_customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc1.account_type_id = 10000
and sysdate between cnh1.effective_start_date and cnh1.effective_end_date
and cnh1.customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and rc1.reference_code = cnh.general_1
and rc1.reference_type_id = 1012882)
select  sc.schedule_name "SCHEDULE_NAME",
        acc.account_name "ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh.node_name "NODE_NAME",
        cnt.customer_node_type_name "Market Segment",cnh.Hierarchy_level, acc.account_name "ROOT_ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh.node_name "ROOT_NODE_NAME",
        mr.code_label "Market Region"
        from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,market_reg mr
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level = 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and acc.account_name = mr.ACCOUNT_NAME
union 
select  sc.schedule_name "SCHEDULE_NAME",
        acc.account_name "ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh.node_name "NODE_NAME",
        cnt.customer_node_type_name "Market Segment",cnh.Hierarchy_level, acc1.account_name "ROOT_ACCOUNT_NAME",
        cnh1.node_name "ROOT_NODE_NAME",
        mr.code_label "Market Region"
from customer_node_history cnh,account acc,schedule sc,customer_node_type cnt,
account  acc1,customer_node_history cnh1,,market_reg mr
where acc.customer_node_id = cnh.customer_node_id 
and cnh.customer_node_status_code = 3
and acc.account_type_id = 10000
and sc.schedule_id = cnh.schedule_id
and cnh.Hierarchy_level != 1
and cnh.customer_node_type_id = cnt.customer_node_type_id
and sysdate between cnh.effective_start_date and cnh.effective_end_date
and cnh.root_customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc1.account_type_id = 10000
and sysdate between cnh1.effective_start_date and cnh1.effective_end_date
and cnh1.customer_node_id = acc1.customer_node_id
and acc.account_name = mr.ACCOUNT_NAME;
```